# How to redirect to a url after drag and drop upload finishes

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm using drag & drop to upload images to replace a users avatar.  It's working fine, but I'm having difficulty in working out where to put code for redirect once the upload has finished.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
addRemoveLinks: true,
init: function() {
thisDropzone = this;
//listen to removedfile event
thisDropzone.on('removedfile', function(file){
$.get('avatar_handler.php?userid=id<?php echo $id2use; ?   >&action=remove&page=avatar&name='+file.name);
});
}
}
</script>
```

And my handler script:

```
switch( $action ) {
case 'upload':
if ( !empty($_FILES) ) {
storeFile($_FILES);
}
break;
case 'remove':
$filename = $_GET['name'];
removeFile( $filename );
break;
case 'show':
showFiles();
break;
}
function showFiles()
{
$result = array();
$files = scandir(DES);
if ( false!==$files ) {
foreach ( $files as $file ) {
//ignore current and parent folder indicator
if ( '.'!=$file && '..'!=$file) {
$obj['name'] = $file;
$obj['size'] = filesize(DES.$file);
$result[] = $obj;
}
}
}
header('Content-type: text/json');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
}
function storeFile( $file )
{
$tempFile = $file['file']['tmp_name'];

//move file to server
$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DS. DES ;
$targetFile = $targetPath. time().$file['file']['name'];
** THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO DO A REDIRECT - after files is saved **
}
function removeFile( $fileName ) {
$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DS. DES ;
$targetFile = $targetPath. $fileName;
//remove only when file exists
if ( file_exists($targetFile) ) {
unlink($targetFile);
}
}
```

Whenever I try adding to the handler.  The script errors

```
//show stored files
$.get('avatar_handler.php?userid=id<?php echo $id2use; ?>&action=show&page=avatar',   function(data) {
$.each(data, function(key,value){
var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size };
thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);
thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile,
"usermedia/id<?php echo getuserid(); ?>/avatar/"+value.name); 
});
},success: function(msg) {
window.location = 'http://mymusicwall.co.uk';
});
```

The above is what I tried. Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would put a redirect into the `success` function of your `$.get` call:

```
$.get(
    url: 'avatar_handler.php',
    data: {
        userid: 'id<?php echo $id2use;?>',
        action: 'remove',
        page: 'avatar',
        name: file.name
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        window.location = 'http://yourredirectlocation.com';
    }    
);
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Hi,Thanks for quick response.  I tried the following with no success.

Comment: Problem must be elsewhere then. I'd suggest you edit your question and be more specific about where the problem is.

Comment: Hi,  I've edited it, just waiting for approval - thanks

Comment: Actually, you tried to edit scrowler's answer.  If you want to provide more clarification do so in your question, or here in the comments. The edit has been rejected.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that!!  Not really used the site much as generally able to resolve things myself.  Stephen

Comment: Hi,  I've managed to work it out based on answer above using: this.on('success', function(file) { redirect }).  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
document.location = '<redirect_location_url>';
```

in the success of your drag function